# Using google maps transit info to show travel duration

Tags: javascript, google-maps, undefined

I have created a map solution, which locates the nearest teacher by distance and the travel time by public transport. But i have an issue looping trough the function that calculates the travel duration (calculateDuration();). Im not recieving any errors, but it returns "undefined".

How my script is set up:

```js
/* 
Json i passed through the API ex.:

{
"status": "success",
"message": "Data selected from database",
"data": [
{
"id": "962",
"status": "Active",
"name": "Name name",
"lat": "55.690606",
"lng": "12.565927",
"subjects": "Subjects....",
"study": "Matematik, Københavns Universitet"
},
*/

(function() {
 window.onload = function() {
  // Setting up vars
  var json = $.getJSON('/api/v1/teachers_by_location', function(data) { 
  var out = data.data; 
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.6764184, 12.569247200000063),
          zoom: 13,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
   var distanceObj = [], i = 0;
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({map:map});
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;

  // Student marker
  latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(55.6764184, 12.569247200000063);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: latLng,
   map: map,
   animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
   title: "Customer"
  });

     $.each(out, function (a, b) {
   distanceObj[i] = { distance: calculateDistance(55.6764184, 12.569247200000063, b.lng, b.lat), duration: calculateDuration(directionsService, b.lng, b.lat), location: a, name: b.name, subjects: b.subjects, study: b.study };
         ++i;
     });

     distanceObj.sort(function (a, b) {
         return parseInt(a.distance) - parseInt(b.distance)
     });

     $.each(distanceObj, function (a, b) {
      $('#list').append('<tr><td>' + b.name + '</td><td>' + b.study + '</td><td>' + b.subjects + '</td><td>' + b.distance + 'm (' + b.duration + ')</td></tr>');
     });

     function calculateDistance(meineLongitude, meineLatitude, long1, lat1) {
         erdRadius = 6371;
         meineLongitude = meineLongitude * (Math.PI / 180);
         meineLatitude = meineLatitude * (Math.PI / 180);
         long1 = long1 * (Math.PI / 180);
         lat1 = lat1 * (Math.PI / 180);
         x0 = meineLongitude * erdRadius * Math.cos(meineLatitude);
         y0 = meineLatitude * erdRadius;
         x1 = long1 * erdRadius * Math.cos(lat1);
         y1 = lat1 * erdRadius;
         dx = x0 - x1;
         dy = y0 - y1;
         d = Math.sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy));
         return Math.round(d * 1000);
     };

  function calculateDuration(directionsService, long2, lat2) {
  var lat3 = parseFloat(lat2);
  var long3 = parseFloat(long2);

    directionsService.route({
      origin: {lat: lat3, lng: long3},
      destination: {lat: <?php echo $lat; ?>, lng: <?php echo $lng; ?>},
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode['TRANSIT']
    }, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        return response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text;
      } else {
        return "Error";
      }
    });
  };

  // Looping through the JSON data
  for (var i = 0, length = out.length; i < length; i++) {
   var data = out[i],
   latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
   // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map,
    title: data.name
   });
   // Creating a closure to retain the correct data, notice how I pass the current data in the loop into the closure (marker, data)
   (function(marker, data) {
    // Attaching a click event to the current marker
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
     infoWindow.setContent(data.name);
     infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
   })(marker, data);
  }


  });
 }
})();
```

```css
  body {
   font-family: helvetica;
  }
  #map { 
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 30%;
   height: 100%; 
  }
  #list_holder { 
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 70%;
   height: 100%; 
   overflow-y: scroll;
  }
  #list { 
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%; 
  }
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
 <div id="map"></div>
 <div id="list_holder">
  <table id="list" border="1">
   <tr>
    <td colspan="4">Nærmeste undervisere:</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
```

Can anybody help me?

UPDATE: 
When modifying the script like so:

```
    function calculateDuration(directionsService, long2, lat2) {
    var lat3 = parseFloat(lat2);
    var long3 = parseFloat(long2);

      directionsService.route({
        origin: {lat: lat3, lng: long3},
        destination: {lat: <?php echo $lat; ?>, lng: <?php echo $lng; ?>},
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode['TRANSIT']
      }, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          //return response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text;
          //console.log("hej");
          console.log(response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text);
        } else {
          //return "Error";
          console.log("error");
        }
      });
    };
```

It console.logs:

121 error
3 timer 49 min.
3 timer 14 min.
3 timer 32 min.
3 timer 21 min.
3 timer 48 min.
3 timer 20 min.
3 timer 21 min.
3 timer 16 min.
3 timer 18 min.
58 min.

So why the undefined when i try to return the text?

Comment: The DirectionsService is asynchronous, you can't return anything from its callback function, you have to use the data when/where it is available (inside the callback function)

Comment: Could you give me an example to work with geocodezip? :)

Comment: There are lots of duplicates available in SO (if not you exact question, then the same problem).  Possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [Directions Service docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Legs):

> - `duration` indicates the total duration of this leg, as a `Duration`
>     object of the following form:
>
>   - `value` indicates the duration in seconds.
>   - `text` contains a string representation of the duration.
>
> These fields **may be undefined** if the duration is unknown.

As you got `google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK`, your `DirectionsResult` is fine, try to use some parts of it that are not undefined :). `console.log(JSON.stringify(response));` will help you to see which ones.